# Legality, implementation, and viability of using the BSP map format in a procedurally generated XNA game?

Tags: xna, c#, maps, procedural-generation, binary-space-partitioning

First off, this is *not* a "which technology should I use" type of question, but rather a question about the viability (And legality, and how to implement) BSP *maps* into an XNA game.

1. The legality part - is the BSP map format (**NOT** bsp trees) an open format? I can find very little information on the map format, and what little I *can* find, is regarding Q3BSP - which makes me think that it's either closed, license-only, or GPL.
2. Is it viable, or wise to use BSP maps for a procedurally generated (I.e. Random dungeon) 3d world, in XNA? BSP is the first format that came to mind since Valve and Id seem to use it for all their games and it works well there. Are there more modern, or otherwise better methods out there? I've seen people using BSPs to generate random dungeons/maps before, but there always seemed to be lighting problems. I'm not sure if that was an issue with the engine (Quake 3), or the format.

Comment: "Are there existing libraries that can get me started" is the same as a which technology to use question and "where should I begin" is a where to get started question. I suggest you remove part two of your questions.